Running vscode debugger on python file does not seem to be producing any results
I'm using vscode windows to debug a python project
If I right click the file and press run file in terminal it runs fine with this command:
C:/Users/rmarr/Documents/python-envs/.mlagents/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/rmarr/Documents/python-envs/.mlagents/Lib/site-packages/mlagents/learn-copy.py

However running it in the python debugger does not produce any results
config.json:
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
          {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",  // You can use "debugpy" as well
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/learn-copy.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false  // Set this to false to debug all code
          }
        ]
    }

When I click run I get on the cli:
cmd /C "c:\Users\rmarr\Documents\python-envs\.mlagents\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\rmarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 57348 -- C:\Users\rmarr\Documents\python-envs\.mlagents\Lib\site-packages\mlagents/learn-copy.py 

I made sure that both the regular and debugger terminal are signed into the virtual environment.
Also I'm working with the unity mlagents code which is not my own but I specified "justMyCode": false in the config.json which I expect to take care of this.
I also set breakpoints in the code
Update: if I use my environment with Python 3.12.6 it works fine however I need to use my environment with 3.7.0. Not sure how this changes the outcome

Please provide more detail about your project as there is little information about your code and no detailed steps to reproduce your issue.

I'm realizing the code itself does not matter the issue is that the debugger will not run anything. I'm using a venv with python 3.7 on windows and using it in vscode.

Hi, I've checked the debugger extension and confirmed that it is no longer supporting Python version <3.8.
